# Creating a progress bar for sentiment analysis in R

Tags: progress-bar, sentiment-analysis, vader, sentimentr

I am trying to do a sentiment analysis using the vader package in R. The vader package involves the vader_df() function to get sentiments for entire columns of data frames. I got a big data frame with approximately 3 million entries, where the analysis takes a lot of time when I run the code.

I used the code

```
sentiment_scores <- vader_df(final_df_filtered$Tweet_text)
```

to get the sentiment scores for the tweets. However, I struggle to come up with a solution to create a progress bar for this process. I tried to use the progress library but I am not really sure how to implement this in my function. Thanks for any help!